# how to select for multiple column values including NULL without repeating column name?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So far I'm doing it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column in(var1,var2,var3) or column is NULL
```

I have issues with repeating column name two times here since in() can't take null as an argument, it returns also no error, just 0 columns. (Maybe some magic variables that can refer last called column ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
'column'
```

is a string literal, not a column name. So this:

```
'column' in(var1,var2,var3) or 'column' is NULL
```

won't match anything unless `var1`, `var2`, or `var3` happen to be the string `'column'`. Try dropping the quotes on the column name:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column in (var1, var2, var3) or column is NULL
```

Comment: of course, you are right with quotes, but that doesn't answer my question, I need a way to rewrite this query so column name is referenced only once

Comment: @user393087: Why would you need to do such a thing? Since `NULL = x` is false for all `x` you won't be able to do it, handling NULL almost always require a special case. Perhaps you should include a real query along with a schema and some sample data to clarify what your problem is.

Comment: I need to write function that converts array into a string with in() that is added then at the end of a query and it would be good if that function could be column name agnostic.

Comment: Well, well, well... `select * from table_name where coalesce(column_name, -1) in (1,2,3,-1); ` - you must be sure that -1 isnt in column

Comment: @user393087: You can't, NULL has to be treated specially all the time. You could say `COALESCE(column, '') IN ('this','that','other','')` to use an empty string instead of `NULL` but then you can't just tack something onto the end of an existing query. Your function needs to take the column name as an argument so that you can tack on the `column IS NULL` bit if necessary.

Comment: @user393087: You commented while I was writing mine. But using COALESCE means that your function needs to know the column name so that it can write that whole part of the WHERE clause and if you're doing that you should just use `IS NULL` and save yourself the trouble of using a sentinel value as a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

Another option without repeating column name:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE coalesce(column,'NULL') in (var1,var2,var3,'NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a union select:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `table_name` 
WHERE 
  `column` IN (var1, var2, var3)
UNION
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `table_name`
  WHERE
    `column` IS NULL
```

Comment: this also repeats column name two times, of course ideal would be `select * from table where column in(1,2,3,null)` - but therre is a bug with null and in() in sqlite3

Comment: No, it does not repeat the column name. This will only repeat the column name if YOU have repeated it in your SELECT.